# Socket is not connected

Tags: java, sockets, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to make `GET` request using proxy. Below is the codes

**Code 1**

```
    // Proxy
    Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url).proxy("127.0.0.1", 8888);

    connection.userAgent(Constants.USER_AGENT);
    connection.timeout(Constants.TIME_OUT);

    connection.get();
```

**Code 2**

```
    URL url = new URL(myUrl);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 8889)); // or whatever your proxy is
    HttpURLConnection uc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(proxy);

    uc.connect();

      String line = null;
      StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
      while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        tmp.append(line);
      }

      Document doc = Jsoup.parse(String.valueOf(tmp));
```

But both are throwing below exception. I also try with different ports like 8898 etc but everytime its throwing below exception, so it means that there is not issue with the port.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:484)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient$1.run(HttpClient.java:482)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.privilegedOpenServer(HttpClient.java:481)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:522)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1202)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1181)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:966)
at Test.main(Test.java:38)
```

If I try to make request without proxy, it works fine. What's the issue ?

PS: I am using Jsoup v1.9.1

Comment: Stack trace please, in your question.

Comment: @EJP question is updated.

Comment: @Junaid the code is working fine for me. I only receive the same exception when port 8888 is closed. Are you sure it's open and not blocked by something? Is telnet able to access the port?

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens so is it network issue ?